# Rails - validation ignores condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, model, conditional-statements

I have these two validation rules:

```
  attr_accessor :validate_step
  validates :full_name, :presence => {:message => 'Full Name cannot be blank.'}, :allow_blank => true, :length => {:minimum => 3, :maximum => 50}, :if => :step_two?
  validates :birthdate, :presence => {:message => 'Birthdate cannot be blank.'}, :if => :step_two?

  def step_two?
    validate_step == 'two'
  end
```

And here is the form:

```
= form_for @user, :validate => true do |f|
  = hidden_field_tag :validate_step, 'two'
  .control-group
    = f.label 'Full Name'
    = f.text_field :full_name
  .control-group
    = f.label 'Birthdate'
    = f.text_field :birthdate
```

This is the second step of the form. When I leave these 2 fields empty, evertyhing is saved, I don't see the expected validation errors.

I've tried to do also something like this:

```
  validates :full_name, :presence => {:message => 'Full Name cannot be blank.'}, :allow_blank => true, :length => {:minimum => 3, :maximum => 50}, :if => Proc.new { |user| user.validate_step == 'two' }
  validates :birthdate, :presence => {:message => 'Birthdate cannot be blank.'}, :if => Proc.new { |user| user.validate_step == 'two' }
```

But the result was the same, I don't see the validation errors - what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You've used `hidden_field_tag` so you are causing `params[:validate_step]` to be set instead of `params[:user][:validate_step]`. As a result the value never makes it to your model, so `step_two` will always return false.

Instead you should use

```
f.hidden_field :validate_step, :value => 'two'
```

Comment: Oh, what a stupid mistake... Thanks Frederick. There is one more thing - can I use live validation now? Because it doesn't work at the moment.